# Copy files and rename - Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I know there are already a couple of StackOverflow posts regarding copying and renaming for Gradle but sadly none seem to be applicable to my issue...

I'm trying to copy and rename files from multiple directories, here's my approach:

```
task copyReportsForDocs(type: Copy) {
        from rootProject.files("path1",
                "path2",
                "path3",
                "path4")
        into genDir

        rename '(.*)_$d_(.*)', '$1$2'
    }
```

The files which should be renamed look something like this:

```
captured_0_foobar_request.adoc
captured_0_foobar_response.adoc
captured_1_fuubar_request.adoc
captured_1_fuubar_response.adoc
```

I just need the front portion to be deleted so it looks something like this:

```
foobar_request.adoc
foobar_response.adoc
fuubar_request.adoc
fuubar_response.adoc
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
task copyReportsForDocs(type: Sync) {
    from(rootProject.file("path")) {
    include '**/*foo*'
    rename 'captured_\\d+_(.+)', '$1'
    }
}
```